# May I know why its impossible for an index to speed up query processing for certain queries?

Tags: sql, indexing, sqlplus

I have tried to explain and display an execution plan for this query:

Explain plan for

```
SELECT *
FROM LINEITEM
WHERE l_quantity = 6
   OR l_shipMode = 'MAIL';

SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

The output is:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 98068815

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation     | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   287K|    34M|  8802   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| LINEITEM |   287K|    34M|  8802   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I created an index on `l_quantity` and `l_shipMode`:

```
CREATE INDEX lineItemIdx ON LINEITEM(l_quantity, l_shipMode);
```

Then I explain and display the execution plan again:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 98068815

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation     | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |   287K|    34M|  8802   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| LINEITEM |   287K|    34M|  8802   (1)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is no difference. Shouldn't the query now be using the index?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, most databases do a very poor job optimizing `or` expressions (Oracle is an exception).

You can get what you want using `union all`:

```
SELECT li.*
FROM LINEITEM li
WHERE l_quantity = 6
UNION ALL
SELECT li.*
FROM LINEITEM li
WHERE l_shipMode = 'MAIL' AND l_quantity <> 6;
```

For this, you need *two* indexes:  `LINEITEM(l_quantity)` and `LINEITEM(l_shipMode, l_quantity)`.

Comment: What is li.* and why is there li beside the table name? Sorry, I never seen such syntax before

Comment: @Astoach167 . . . That is a table alias and a column wildcard qualified with the table alias.

Answer (score 2):

In your query you have two conditions combined with an `OR` clause:

```
 WHERE l_quantity = 6
    OR l_shipMode = 'MAIL';
```

This implies that for an evalaution of the filter criteria the index

```
 INDEX lineItemIdx ON LINEITEM(l_quantity, l_shipMode);
```

can't work properly for the each one of the two parts of the OR clause..

So the query needs a full scan and the index in not useful.

The index in this case should be useful only with the condition

```
WHERE l_quantity = 6
```

or

```
WHERE l_quantity = 6
  AND l_shipMode = 'MAIL';
```

or use two indexes and rebuild the query suing tow separated  queries based on UNION